# Three.js positioning squares in a circle

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I have a circular grid filled with squares. Everything seems to be ok except for the part where I need to center all the squares within the circle to it's center.

The whole circular grids is always aligned more to the right, even though the center point seems to be correct.

I suspect it's either the calaculation to remove all the squares that are not within the circle area or the part where I'm centering the grid.

**[Update]:** Thanks to Wilt's hint, I was able to fix my calculations of center point for both `Galaxy` and `AOS` circles.

I have also updated the below example.

```
Grid.prototype.generate = function(){

    this.galaxyCircle = {
        pos: {
            x: this.pos.x ,
            y: this.pos.y,
            z: this.pos.z ,
        },
        r: (this.grid_size / 2),
    };

    this.add_center_point( this.galaxyCircle.pos, 0x033d6ff );

    this.AOS_settings = { //// Area of Sight ////
        x: this.galaxyCircle.x,
        y: this.galaxyCircle.z,
        r: 64, //// radius ////
        color: 0x33cccc
    };
    this.add_circle_border( this.AOS_settings );

    ////// fill the grid with square cells ////////
    for ( var row = 0; row < this.size.rows; row++){
        for ( var col = 0; col < this.size.cols; col++){
            this.add_cell2grid( row, col );
        }
    }

    this.position.set( this.pos.x , this.pos.y, this.pos.z );
    ///// center the grid /////
    this.cells.position.set( this.pos.x - ((this.size.rows * this.sq_size) / 2), this.pos.y, this.pos.z -  ((this.size.cols * this.sq_size) / 2) );
    this.add( this.cells );

    //// map borders  /////
    this.add_circle_border({ 
        r: (this.grid_size / 2),
        color: 0x00ff00
    });
    this.add_square_border( this.grid_size , 0xffff00);
    this.add_center_point();
    //// map borders  /////
};
```

See the full example below:

```js
var renderer, camera, scene, controls, n_grid;

///////// [ Square ] ////////////
var Square = function(options) {
  if (typeof options != "undefined") {
    this.attr = {
      coords: options.coords || [],
      size: options.size,
      margin: options.margin || 0,
      pos: options.b_pos,
      opacity: options.opacity || 1,
      id: typeof(options.coords) == "undefined" ? -1 : options.coords[0] + "" + options.coords[1],
    };

    var cell_size = (this.attr.size + (this.attr.margin * 2));

    this.colors = {
      selected: 0x40ff00,
      hover: 0x00ff00,
      path: 0x3399ff,
      ship: {
        selected: 0xff8000,
        hover: 0xff5c33
      },
      base: parseInt(options.color)
    };

    this.states = {
      selected: false,
      hovered: false,
      isPath: false,
      isPlayer: false
    };

    var rectGeom = this.generate_lines();
    var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
      side: THREE.DoubleSide,
      color: options.color,
      transparent: true,
      opacity: this.attr.opacity
    }); ///// color not being changed!!!???/   ///

    THREE.Line.call(this, rectGeom, material);

    this.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
    if (this.attr.coords.length == 0) {
      this.position.set(this.attr.pos.x, this.attr.pos.y, this.attr.pos.z);
    } else {
      this.position.set(this.attr.pos.x + (this.attr.coords[0] * cell_size) + this.attr.margin + (cell_size / 2), this.attr.pos.y, this.attr.pos.z + (this.attr.coords[1] * cell_size) + this.attr.margin + (cell_size / 2));
    }

    /*this.center_pos = { ///// pos of center point ///
     x: ( this.position.x + (cell_size / 2) ) + 0.5, 
     y: ( this.position.z + (cell_size / 2) ) + 0.5
    };*/

    this.rotation.set((Math.PI / 2), 0, 0);

  } else {
    console.error("[Square] no parameters defined. ]");
  }
}

Square.prototype = Object.create(THREE.Line.prototype);
Square.prototype.constructor = Square;

///// State handlers ////
Square.prototype.toggleState = function(state) {
  this.states[state] = !this.states[state];
};

Square.prototype.checkState = function(state) {
  return this.states[state];
};
/////// Mouse events ////
Square.prototype.mouseOver = function() {
  if (!this.checkState("hovered")) {
    if (!this.checkState("selected")) {
      this.toggleState("hovered");
      this.change_color(this.colors.hover, 0.8);
    }
  }
};
Square.prototype.mouseOut = function() {
  if (this.checkState("hovered")) {
    if (!this.checkState("selected")) {
      this.change_color(this.colors.base);
      this.toggleState("hovered");
    }
  }
};
Square.prototype.select = function() {
  if (!this.checkState("selected")) {
    this.toggleState("selected");
    this.change_color(this.colors.selected, 1);
  }
};
Square.prototype.unselect = function() {
  if (this.checkState("selected")) {
    this.toggleState("selected");
    this.change_color(this.colors.base);
  }
};
/////// Mouse events ////

Square.prototype.change_color = function(color, opacity) {
  this.material.color.setHex(color);
  this.material.opacity = opacity || this.attr.opacity;
};

Square.prototype.generate_lines = function() {
  var rectShape = new THREE.Shape();
  var half_size = (this.attr.size / 2);
  rectShape.autoClose = true;
  rectShape.moveTo(-half_size, -half_size);
  rectShape.lineTo(half_size, -half_size);
  rectShape.lineTo(half_size, half_size);
  rectShape.lineTo(-half_size, half_size);
  return rectShape.createPointsGeometry();
};
///////// [ Square ] ////////////

/////// [ Circle ] ////////////////
var Circle = function(options) {
  if (typeof options != "undefined") {
    //console.log("[Circle] Initializing");
    this.attr = {
      segments: options.segments,
      radius: options.radius,
      color: options.color,
      pos: options.pos
    }

    var segments = this.generate_segments();
    var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
      color: options.color,
      transparent: true,
      opacity: options.opacity
    });
    THREE.Line.call(this, segments, material);

    this.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
    this.position.set(options.pos.x, options.pos.y, options.pos.z); //// x,y,z //// 
    this.rotation.set((Math.PI / 2), 0, 0);
  } else {
    console.error("[Circle] no parameters defined. ]");
  }
};

Circle.prototype = Object.create(THREE.Line.prototype);
Circle.prototype.constructor = Circle;

Circle.prototype.generate_segments = function() {
  var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
  for (var s = 0; s <= this.attr.segments; s++) {
    var theta = (s / this.attr.segments) * Math.PI * 2;
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(Math.cos(theta) * this.attr.radius, Math.sin(theta) * this.attr.radius, 0));
  }
  return geometry;
};
/////// [ Circle ] ////////////////

///////////// [ Grid ] ////////////////
var Grid = function(options) {
  if (typeof options !== "undefined") {
    //console.log("[Grid] Initializing");
    this.cell_settings = options.cell;
    this.grid_size = options.size;

    THREE.Object3D.call(this);

    this.pos = {
      x: options.pos.x,
      y: options.pos.y,
      z: options.pos.z
    };

    var sq_margin = (this.cell_settings.margin * 2);
    this.sq_size = this.cell_settings.size + sq_margin;
    this.size = {
      w: this.grid_size[0] * this.sq_size,
      h: this.grid_size[1] * this.sq_size
    };
    console.log(this.grid_size)

    this.cells = new THREE.Object3D();

    this.cells_in_AOS = []; //// cells in Area of Sight ////

    this.galaxyCircle = {
      pos: {
        x: this.pos.x + (this.size.w / 2),
        y: this.pos.y,
        z: this.pos.z + (this.size.w / 2),
      },
      r: (this.size.w / 2),
    };

    var c = (this.galaxyCircle.r - options.AOS.r);

    this.AOS_circle = { //// Area of Sight ////
      pos: {
        x: this.galaxyCircle.pos.x,
        y: this.galaxyCircle.pos.y,
        z: this.galaxyCircle.pos.z
      },
      r: options.AOS.r, //// radius ////
      color: 0x33cccc
    };

    console.log(this.AOS_circle)

    this.generate();
  } else {
    console.error("[Grid] no parameters defined. ]");
  }
};

Grid.prototype = Object.create(THREE.Object3D.prototype);
Grid.prototype.constructor = Grid;

Grid.prototype.generate = function() {
  //////////////// Galaxy center point //////
  this.add_center_point(this.galaxyCircle.pos, 0x033d6ff);
  ////// AOS circle border ////
  this.add_circle_border(this.AOS_circle);

  ////// fill the grid with square cells ////////
  for (var row = 0; row < this.grid_size[0]; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < this.grid_size[1]; col++) {
      this.add_cell2grid(row, col);
    }
  }

  this.position.set(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.pos.z);
  ///// center the grid /////
  this.cells.position.set(this.pos.x - ((this.grid_size[0] * this.sq_size) / 2), this.pos.y, this.pos.z - ((this.grid_size[1] * this.sq_size) / 2));
  this.add(this.cells);

  //// map borders  /////
  this.add_circle_border({
    r: (this.size.w / 2),
    color: 0x00ff00
  });
  this.add_square_border(this.size.w, 0xffff00);
  this.add_center_point();
  //// map borders  /////
};

Grid.prototype.add_center_point = function(pos, color) {
  var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.5, 5.5, 0.5)
  if (typeof pos === "object") {
    geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.5, 10.5, 0.5);
  }
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: color || 0xcc33ff
  });
  var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  if (typeof pos !== "object") {
    cube.position.set(0, 0, 0);
  } else {
    cube.position.set(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);
  }
  this.add(cube)
};

Grid.prototype.add_cell2grid = function(row, col) {
  var cell = new Square({
    coords: [row, col],
    size: this.cell_settings.size,
    margin: this.cell_settings.margin,
    opacity: this.cell_settings.opacity,
    color: 0xFFFFFF,
    b_pos: {
      x: this.pos.x,
      y: this.pos.y,
      z: this.pos.z
    } //// base position ///
  });

  if (this.isColidingWith(this.galaxyCircle, cell)) {
    if (!this.is_in_AOS(cell)) {
      cell.visible = false;
    } else {
      this.cells_in_AOS.push(cell);
    }

    if (this instanceof THREE.Object3D) {
      this.cells.add(cell);
    } else {
      console.error("[Grid] is not THREE.Object3D type. ");
    }
  }
};

Grid.prototype.is_in_AOS = function(cell) { //// Circle colision ////
  return this.isColidingWith(this.AOS_circle, cell)
};

Grid.prototype.isColidingWith = function(cA, cell) { //// Circle colision ////
  var d_x = cA.pos.x - cell.position.x;
  var d_y = cA.pos.z - cell.position.z;
  var dist = Math.sqrt(d_x * d_x + d_y * d_y);

  if (dist < (cA.r - (cell.attr.size / 2))) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};

Grid.prototype.getCellAt = function(p) {
  this.wColiisions.postMessage([p.x, p.y]);
};

Grid.prototype.add_circle_border = function(options) {
  var circle = new Circle({
    segments: 50,
    radius: options.r,
    color: options.color,
    opacity: 0.5,
    pos: {
      x: this.pos.x,
      y: 0.5,
      z: this.pos.z
    }
  });

  this.add(circle);
};

Grid.prototype.add_square_border = function(square_size, color) {
  var square = new Square({
    size: square_size,
    color: color,
    b_pos: { //// base position ///
      x: this.pos.x,
      y: this.pos.y,
      z: this.pos.z
    }
  });

  this.add(square);
};
///////////// [ Grid ] ////////////////

////// Initializers ////////////////////////
function initEvents() {
  //console.log("- Events");
  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
  renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);
  renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
}

function initRenderer() {
  //console.log("- Renderer");
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  renderer.setClearColor(0x264d73, 1);
}

function initScene() {
  //console.log("- Scene")
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
}

function initCamera() {
  //console.log("- Camera");
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.set(0, 390, 0);
  camera.lookAt(scene.position);
  scene.add(camera);

  //controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera , renderer.domElement );
}

function initLights() {
  console.log("- Lights");
  var aLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xD0D0D0, 0.5);
  scene.add(aLight);
}

function initGrid() {
  n_grid = new Grid({
    size: [20, 20],
    pos: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      z: 0
    },
    cell: {
      size: 7,
      margin: 0,
      opacity: 0.4
    },
    AOS: {
      r: 30
    }
  });

  scene.add(n_grid);
}
////// Initializers ////////////////////////

///// Mouse events ////////
function onMouseMove(e) {}
///// Mouse events ////////

///// Main /////////
function main() {
  //console.log(" Initializing: ");
  initRenderer(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  initScene();
  initCamera(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  initLights();
  initGrid();
  //InitEvents();
  animate();
}

function animate() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render_all();
}

function render_all() {
  //controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

main();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r77/three.js"></script>
<header>
  <style>
    body canvas {
      width: 100%, height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
</header>
<body>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shared a lot of code, but could it be that you draw the rectangles like this:

```
a = ( 0, 0);    d-----c
b = (10, 0);    |     |
c = (10,10);    |     |
d = ( 0,10);    a-----b
```

while you should do like this:

```
a = (-5,-5);    d-----c
b = ( 5,-5);    |     |
c = ( 5, 5);    |     |
d = (-5, 5);    a-----b
```

It is just a guess...

Comment: it wasn't just this ... but also that I incorrectly calculated the center point of both `Galaxy_circle` and `AOS_circle`. It's now working properly. , thanks for your input. I've also corrected my example above.